# The Gemoro (& Bartenura on the mishna) quotes pessukim out of order; why?

Tags: mishna, masechet-yoma, bartenura

Bartenura comments on the mishna in [Yoma Perek 8(1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Yoma.8.1?lang=bi&with=Bartenura&lang2=en) that there are five Torah references to affliction of the soul on Yom Kippur. The pessukim in the order in which he quotes them are:

[Vayikro 23:32](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9924/showrashi/true#v32)

> It is a complete day of rest for you, and you shall afflict
>   yourselves. On the ninth of the month in the evening, from evening to
>   evening, you shall observe your rest day.

[Vayikro 16:31](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9917/showrashi/true#v31)

> It is a Sabbath of rest for you, and you shall afflict yourselves. It
>   is an eternal statute.

[Bamidbor 29:7](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9957/showrashi/true)

> And on the tenth day of this seventh month, there shall be a holy
>   convocation for you, and you shall afflict your souls. You shall not
>   perform any work.

[Vayikro 23:27](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9924/showrashi/true#v27)

> But on the tenth of this seventh month, it is a day of atonement, it
>   shall be a holy occasion for you; you shall afflict yourselves, and
>   you shall offer up a fire offering to the Lord

[Vayikro 16:29](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9917/showrashi/true#v29)

> And [all this] shall be as an eternal statute for you; in the seventh
>   month, on the tenth of the month, you shall afflict yourselves, and
>   you shall not do any work neither the native nor the stranger who
>   dwells among you.

Why does he quote  them out of their order in the Torah?

Thanks to @DonielF who pointed out that that is the order the Gemara quotes them (Yoma 76a).

Comment: Why they should be in order? Is there any significance? Can you quote the psukim, maybe we can find something.

Comment: It could be in order of relevance rather than when they appear in the torah.

Comment: He note that the number of types of pain equals to the number of verses. You may want to mention that in your question, as it may help potential answerers find an answer. (E.g., perhaps each verse corresponds to a specific verse.)

Comment: That’s the order the Gemara quotes them (Yoma 76a)

Comment: That @DonielF is an answer - which of course suggests the next question - why does the Gemoro choose that order?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Precisely why I didn’t post it as an answer; I felt it would improve the question to rephrase it as asking on the Gemara instead of the Bartenura.